# Python Selenium cant find the element on an overlay

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to fill an form automatically in a website but i cannot find any specific identifier on input part. The problem starts after **while** section. Program clicks on the button but afterwise it cannot find the element. I tried to use XPATH, CSS but there is no succession. Site is opening an overlay but there is no iframe tags in HTML code so I am stucked.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

usernameStr = 'username'
passwordStr = 'password'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://allzinapp.com/vitrin/')
browser.maximize_window()

time.sleep(2)

username = browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'username')
username.send_keys(usernameStr)

password = browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')
password.send_keys(passwordStr)

button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/vaadin-login-overlay- 
wrapper/vaadin-login-form/vaadin-login-form-wrapper/form/vaadin-button')
button.click()

time.sleep(2)

browser.get('https://allzinapp.com/vitrin/tables')

time.sleep(2)

x = 0
while x < 40:
    tableName = "T{}".format(x)

    plusButton = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/flow-container-vitrin-816189098/vaadin-app-layout/vaadin-vertical-layout[2]/vaadin-form-layout[1]/div/vaadin-button[1]')
    plusButton.click()

    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH, button))

    fillSlot = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@aria-labelledby="vaadin-text-field-label-3 vaadin-text-field-input-3"]').send_keys('Selam')
    fillSlot.send_keys('Teras')

    fillName = browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'Örn:  A1')
    fillName.send_keys(tableName)

    confirmButton = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/vaadin-dialog-overlay/flow-component-renderer/div/vaadin-vertical-layout/vaadin-vertical-layout[1]/vaadin-horizontal-layout/vaadin-button[2]')
    confirmButton.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    x += 1
```

Comment: where exactly are you getting the error?

Comment: fillSlot=browser.find_element